# using redis timeseries in aredes error =>Error handling publish event: [ErrorReply: ERR TSDB: invalid value]

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, aedes

i am using redis timeseries in aedes i want when ever someone publis something is topic that data should store in redis in form of object value : [{status,timestamp},{status,timestamp]

i try this code but giving error
CODE =>

const { createClient } = require('redis');
const { TimeSeriesDuplicatePolicies, TimeSeriesEncoding, TimeSeriesAggregationType } = require('@redis/time-series');

const clt = createClient();

(async () => {

```
try {
    // Connect to Redis before creating the time series
    await clt.connect();

    const created = await clt.ts.create('random', {
        RETENTION: 86400000, // 1 day in milliseconds
        ENCODING: TimeSeriesEncoding.UNCOMPRESSED, // No compression
        DUPLICATE_POLICY: TimeSeriesDuplicatePolicies.BLOCK, // No duplicates
    });

    if (created === 'OK') {
        console.log('Created timeseries.');
    } else {
        console.error('Error creating timeseries:', created);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to Redis or creating timeseries:', error);
}
```

})();

aedes.on('publish', async function (packet, client) {
if (client) {
console.log(`MESSAGE_PUBLISHED : MQTT Client ${(client ? client.id : 'AEDES BROKER_' + aedes.id)} has published message "${packet.payload}" on ${packet.topic} to aedes broker ${aedes.id}`);

```
    try {
        // Convert buffer payload to string
        const payloadString = packet.payload.toString('utf8');
        
        // Parse the payload string as JSON
        const data = JSON.parse(payloadString);
        const timestamp = Date.now();
        // Extract data from the JSON payload
        const deviceId = data.deviceID;
        const nodeId = data.NodeID;
        const status = data.status;

    

      
            const value = {
                status: status,
                timestamp: timestamp
            };
               
           
                const serializedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
            console.log("Data:", data);
            console.log("DID:", deviceId);
            console.log("NODEID:", nodeId);
            console.log("Status:", status);
            console.log("Value to be stored in Redis time series:", value);

            // Add the data to the Redis time series
            const result = await clt.ts.add(`${deviceId}:${nodeId}`, timestamp, serializedValue);
            console.log("Result from Redis:", result)
            console.log(`Added timestamp ${currentTimestamp}, value ${value}.`);
            // console.log("Result from Redis:", result);

            console.log("Data saved to Redis time series.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error handling publish event:", error);
    }
}
```

});

and sending data in postman  =>
{
"deviceID": "23423432",
"NodeID": "34534",
"status":"1"
}

ERROR =>
Data: { deviceID: '23423432', NodeID: '34534', status: '1' }
DID: 23423432
NODEID: 34534
Status: 1
Value to be stored in Redis time series: { status: '1', timestamp: 1711579778262 }
Error handling publish event: [ErrorReply: ERR TSDB: invalid value]

Answer (score 0):

The value that you are trying to store is not numeric.

See [TS.ADD](https://redis.io/commands/ts.add/):

> value
> is (double) numeric data value of the sample. The double number should follow RFC 7159 (JSON standard). In particular, the parser rejects overly large values that do not fit in binary64. It does not accept NaN or infinite values.